# Компиляция python файла в exe

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe

я компилирую скрипт на python в exe файл, у меня помимо библиотек есть 3 dll файла которые нужно было положить в папку с библиотеками python[image: вот] для работы с библиотекой cx_oracle. Так вот, нужно ли мне при компиляции через библиотеку pyinstaller добавлять эти библиотеки в папку со скриптом, или нужно сделать что-то другое для корректной работы exe файла на компьютере на котором не будет ни питона ни этих dll, или он всё сделает сам?

Comment: А попробовать? Скомпилировать. Запустить. Проверить. Заработало? Докинуть дллки. Запустить. Проверить. Заработало? Писать сюда с тем, что "Пробовал запускать без длл и с длл, чего куда надо положить чтобы заработало?" Для теста можешь воткнуть прям на старте гуя запрос в бд с банальным селектом любого поля которое точно есть и месседжбокс который тебе результат запроса выведет.

Comment: Вы можете конвертировать **все свои файлы**, которые в проекте вашем, в`exe` с помощью `pyinstaller`, и созданные папки уже отправлять на другой компьютер, где нет питона и т. п.